# Cant get onclick event to trigger my function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm working on an application that will allow me to click a button on the web page and then start my timer object. However, the timer will not start `onclick`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Timer = function()
    {   
    // Property: Frequency of elapse event of the timer in millisecond
    this.Interval = 1000;
    
    // Property: Whether the timer is enable or not
    this.Enable = new Boolean(false);
    
    // Event: Timer tick
    this.Tick;
    
    // Member variable: Hold interval id of the timer
    var timerId = 0;
    
    // Member variable: Hold instance of this class
    var thisObject;
    
    // Function: Start the timer
    this.Start = function()
    {
      this.Enable = new Boolean(true);
  
      thisObject = this;
      if (thisObject.Enable)
      {
        thisObject.timerId = setInterval(
        function()
        {
          thisObject.Tick(); 
        }, thisObject.Interval);
      }
    };
    // Function: Stops the timer
    this.Stop = function(){     
        thisObject.Enable = new Boolean(false);
        clearInterval(thisObject.timerId);
    };
  
  };
  //counts down the timer
  function timer_tick()
  {
    index  = index - 1;
    document.getElementById("blue").innerHTML =index;
    if (index === 0) 
    {
      obj.Stop();
    }
  }
```

If I remove function `startBlue()` but leave the code inside of it, the timer will run on page load. So after looking at my code I think the issue is where I call `startBlue` (below in the html) or somewhere in this function:

```
function startBlue(){
 var index = 300;
 var obj = new Timer();
 obj.Interval = 1000;
 obj.Tick = timer_tick();
 obj.Start();
}
</script>
<body>
<div id ="Objectives">
 Your Objectives:
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Blue Buff:</label>
 <button id="yosb" onclick ="startBlue();">Start Blue</button>
 <h2 id = "blue">
  </h2>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: onclick ="startBlue();" should be onclick="startBlue();" (NO SPACE BEFORE =)

Comment: If my answer below works for you, please select it as the answer. If not I will be happy to help you out some more.

Comment: vivekvasani, that did the trick thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't the space, it is a scope and reference issue.

```
var index, obj;  //define index and obj outside of startBlue().
function startBlue(){
    index = 300;  //initialize without redefining (remove 'var').
    obj = new Timer();  //initialize without redefining (remove 'var').
    obj.Interval = 1000;
    obj.Tick = timer_tick;  // store the actual function in obj.Tick, not the return (remove the '()' from the end of timer_tick)
    obj.Start();
}
```

If you define a variable inside of a function, then that variable is only accessible inside the scope of that function only. By defining it outside, you allow that variable to be accessed from the outer scope.

To store functions in variables, you must be sure not to include the parens at the end of the function name. Otherwise the function will be executed first, and the return value will then be stored in the variable instead of the function it self.

Answer (score 0):

The following line

```
<button id="yosb" onclick ="startBlue();">Start Blue</button>
```

Should be changed to

```
<button id="yosb" onclick="startBlue();">Start Blue</button>
```

You are adding an unnecessary space between the **onclick** and the **=**.

Comment: I fixed that line, still having issues getting the onclick event to initialize.

Comment: What is the timer being used for?